# Finding the domain of trigonometric function

Tags: functions

I ma supposed to find the domain of $$f:y=\sqrt{\sin \sqrt{x}} $$ I know that the first step is that: $$\sin \sqrt{x}\geq 0$$  and $$x\geq 0$$ When I plot the graph I know that $$\sin \sqrt{x}$$ is $$\geq 0$$ for $$\left [ 0,\infty  \right ]$$, so does for x.
Is it the domain then $$\left [ 0,\infty  \right ]$$?
Thanks

Comment: How did you determine $\sin\sqrt x\geq0$ for all $x\geq0$? For example, what if $x=(3\pi/2)^2$?

Comment: @Clayton I thought is it is from definition of te square root

Comment: did you not use the definition of $\sin(t)$? When is $\sin(t)\ge0$. Yes if $0\le t\le\pi$ but not if $\pi< t<2\pi$. Could you extend this, for a complete solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$sin a\geq 0 \to 0+2k\pi\leq a\leq \pi+2k\pi$$so you put $\sqrt x $ in it to find domain. more than $x\geq 0    $ 
$$\\ sin \sqrt x \geq 0 \to 0+2k\pi\leq \sqrt x\leq \pi+2k\pi$$at the end note that $k$ must be in $\{0,1,2,3,...\}$
 can you take over ?

Comment: We need also $k>0$.